# Python break from socket receive on SIGINT

Tags: python, sockets, signal-handling

I'm working on a program that receives data from a socket, and when a signal is sent, I want to be able to break from the receive.

What I have now:

```
class Killer: 
    die = False
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.terminate)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.terminate)

    def terminate(self, signum, frame):
        print ("caught " + str(signum))
        self.die = True;

sock = socket.socket()
# Generic socket setup

while (~killer.die):
    #generic data setup
    sock.receive(data)

sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

When the interrupt is caught, it prints and then goes back into waiting.

Is there a way to break from the receive on receiving a signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python 3.5, interrupted system calls are [automatically resumed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/) after invoking the (Python) signal handler.  If you don’t want that, raise an exception in your handler.

Comment: Is that the 'coreect' way of handling it? That seems a little hackey

Comment: @BrydonGibson: Yes, that’s what you do: see the PEP.  It’s just part of the language (now) that `EINTR` handling takes place _within_ a blocking call, not between two of them.

Comment: Ah explained that way it makes much more sense, thanks!